# How to use a gaussian wave to trap an atom?

Tags: atomic-physics

The AC stark shift states that the energies of the dressed states of a two level atom will be

$$E_e=\frac{\hbar}{2}(-\Delta-\sqrt{\Omega^2+\Delta^2})$$
$$E_g=\frac{\hbar}{2}(-\Delta+\sqrt{\Omega^2+\Delta^2})$$

With a detuning of $\Delta=-100\Omega$ we have energy shifts that look like (with a very small negative dip in the excited state)
[image]

and with a detuning of $\Delta=100\Omega$ we have energy shifts that look like (with a very small dip in the ground state)

[image]

However, if we use a negative detuning then we will use have to use excited atoms in order to trap an atom, but wouldn't this mean they would vibrate a lot and then immediately leave since they would have some velocity and be unstable.

If we were to use a positive detuning we could use excited atoms. However in reality we use very cold atoms. Where am I going wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Just a hint: you should go back to where you found that formula, and pay close attention to how it is derived, and in particular the use of "dressed" vs "bare" states. When you correctly work out the shift relative to the bare state, you will indeed find that the force on the ground state can be attractive or repulsive, depending on the sign of $\Delta$.

Comment: Good resources for this are anything by Cohen-Tannoudji or Dalibard discussing the dressed state formalism, e.g. https://jila.colorado.edu/arey/sites/default/files/files/the-autler-townes-p109-1996.pdf